# PHP not displaying errors

Tags: php

I have a small script which im using to test PHP mail(), as below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

mail('x@x.com','test','test') or die('could not send') ;

echo "Mail Sent";

?>
```

When I run this script I get no output at all. I don't get an error, I dont get anything echoed, I view the source, nothing.

Ive tried so many different variations, if I take out the mail function in the code above it will work fine.

This is a Windows hosted server so I have not access to php.ini or anything

Could it be some configuration that is causing no output when its encountering an error?

Comment: PS I know that the mail() function will probably error if sendmail_from isnt set or not given in the header im just trying to understand why the errors wont output

Comment: Well, your `mail` call contains a syntax error (`'test,` should have an extra apostrophe). That could be the reason for the program dying ... PHP should tell you that, though, which is probably the point of this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the PHP [Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) guide:

> **Note:** Although `display_errors` may be
>   set at runtime (with `ini_set()`), it
>   won't have any affect if the script
>   has fatal errors. This is because the
>   desired runtime action does not get
>   executed.

Your code appears to have a syntax error (`'test,` is missing a closing apostrophe). Thus, your program is encountering a fatal error. The **only** way to get a fatal error to display (**EDIT**: outside the error log) is to set `display_errors = 1` in your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your sendmail server configuration. If youre testing this script on your personal development environment, don't worry about it. It can be a pita to setup/configure a sendmail server. If you're having this problem on your production server, the simpliest solution is to use a mailer library that has an smtp option (allowi g your email to be sent to an external smtp server for processing/delivery).

Here is a guide on using a 3rd party smtp mail script...
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm